# Code doesn't calculate the score, it is always set on 0

Tags: python, rating

I'm trying to make a code for Paper-Rock-Scissors game and it should read 'rating.txt' file and if there's a record for a person's score start with this score, and if there isn't a record it should start counting from 0. Help me please, here's my code :

```
import random

person = input('Enter your name:')
print('Hello,', person)
score = []


while True: 
   user_move = str(input())
   user_move = user_move.lower()
   
   
   to_win = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
          
   computer_choice = random.choice(to_win)
   
   
   with open('rating.txt') as file:
       for line in file.readlines():
           line_list = line.split()
           if line[0] == person:
               score = int(line[1])
               
   
   if user_move in to_win:
       if user_move == computer_choice:
           print(f'There is a draw ({user_move})')
           score.append(100)
       if user_move == 'rock':
           if computer_choice == 'paper':
               print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}' )
           elif computer_choice == 'scissors':
               print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
               score.append(100)
       if user_move == 'paper':
           if computer_choice == 'scissors':
               print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
           elif computer_choice == 'rock':
               print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
               score.append(100)
       if user_move == 'scissors':
           if computer_choice == 'rock':
               print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
           elif computer_choice == 'paper':
               print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
               score.append(100)
   elif user_move == '!exit':
       print('Bye!')
       break
   elif user_move == '!rating':
           print("Your rating:", sum(score))
   else:
       print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: Your `score` variable is a list of many numbers. Do you want `score` to be a number instead? Several lines later I see `score = int(line[1])` which is a number

Comment: can you share the "rating.txt" file, so we can understand about the error?

Comment: I think `if line[0] == person:` should be `if line_list[0] == person:` and `score = int(line[1])` should be `score.append(line_list[1])` to be consistent with the rest of your code.

Comment: yes @jjramsey sorry for typo

Answer (score 1):

```
if line_list[0] == person:
               score = int(line_list[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found there are several mistakes.

1. You should read a file before `while` loop. Otherwise, your score will be reset again and again regareless of your cumulative score.
2. When you read a file, line[0] should be line_list[0] and line[1] should be line_list[1]. Then score is `int`, not `list`, so all the cumulative score should be calculated as `score += 100`, not `score = score.append(100)`. Therefore, you can print the score using just `score` variable, not `sum(score)` when you type "!rating."
3. `file` is a pre-defined keyword, so you should not use `file` as a alias.

Widh the consideration of your mistakes, I edited your code as follows:

```
import random

person = input('Enter your name:')
print('Hello,', person)
score = []

with open('rating.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
        line_list = line.split()
        if line_list[0] == person:
            score = int(line_list[1])

while True:
    user_move = str(input())
    user_move = user_move.lower()

    to_win = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

    computer_choice = random.choice(to_win)

    if user_move in to_win:
        if user_move == computer_choice:
            print(f'There is a draw ({user_move})')
            score += 100
        if user_move == 'rock':
            if computer_choice == 'paper':
                print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
            elif computer_choice == 'scissors':
                print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
                score += 100
        if user_move == 'paper':
            if computer_choice == 'scissors':
                print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
            elif computer_choice == 'rock':
                print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
                score += 100
        if user_move == 'scissors':
            if computer_choice == 'rock':
                print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
            elif computer_choice == 'paper':
                print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
                score += 100
    elif user_move == '!exit':
        print('Bye!')
        break
    elif user_move == '!rating':
        print("Your rating:", score)
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```